# Are there exotic aspherical manifolds other than the ones constructed via Davis' reflection group trick?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

It is known that for each $n \geq 4$ there exists an aspherical closed $n$-dimensional manifold such that its universal covering is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. There are many constructions in terms of various fundamental groups mainly due to Davis and his collaborators. It seems all of them at some point use the reflection group trick. So I wonder

> Are there exotic aspherical manifolds which are not constructed by the reflection group trick?

I was reminded by a friend that Ancel-Guilbault-Sparks seem to work on a different construction from the ones of Davis. [http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~sale/Seminar/17Spring.html](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Esale/Seminar/17Spring.html)
That is, they can discard the reflection trick.

I remember in the talk Guilbault explained that the construction is based on a point of view of Ancel-Siebenmann in 1985, where they claimed that the universal cover of Davis' manifolds admit a Z-compactification. This is explained in Guilbault's [survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.6741). The following is quoted from P9
[image]

Consider those copies of $C$ as bubbles on a soap. One can somehow shuffle the bubbles around to create more examples.

Maybe this answers the question? I'm not very satisfied because it seems it is still a modification on Davis' construction.

"Is it possible to build an exotic aspherical manifold not based on boundary connected sum of compact contractible manifolds" might be a more accurate question.